# How can I use requests library to upload files to flask web page with a python script?

Tags: python, html, flask, web-applications, python-requests

I made a simple Flask app where I can upload a file on a web page and it gets saved on my PC. I am able to upload files using browser.

This is the Web page Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.images }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And This is the Flask App Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FileField
from flask_uploads import configure_uploads, IMAGES, UploadSet

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret"
app.config["UPLOADED_IMAGES_DEST"] = "img"
images = UploadSet("images", IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, images)
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    images = FileField("images")
@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.images.data)
        filename = images.save(form.images.data)
        return f"Fileame: { filename }"
    return render_template("template.html", form = MyForm())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. It will forward to another server. warning there is poor error checking here. This will upload from flask to flask server.

```
       @route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
       def index(self):
            if request.method == 'GET':
                return render_template('index.html')
    
            if request.method == 'POST':
                uploaded_file = request.files['file']
                task_id = random.getrandbits(16)
    
                if not uploaded_file:
                    logging.info("[+] No tweet data supplied.")
                    return render_template('index.html')
    
                try:
                    response = requests.post("{}/".format("www.someotherhost.com"), files={'file': (uploaded_file.filename, uploaded_file.stream, uploaded_file.content_type, uploaded_file.headers)})
    
                    if response != "Success":
                        print("do something here.")
    
                except Exception as error:
                    logging.info("[-]", str(error))
                    return render_template('index.html')
    
                return redirect(url_for('view:get_task_status', task_id=task_id))
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass a `files` argument to the `requests.post` method which should be a dictionary where the key is `'images'` as defined in your server app, and the value is the file pointer:

```
import requests

def upload(filename):
    headers={'ContentType': 'multipart/form-data'}
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        files = {'images': f}
        url='http://localhost:5000/'
        r = requests.post(url, files=files)
        print (r.content, r.status_code)

upload('some_file.jpg')
```

Comment: In the flask app I can see a new post request has been made, but no file got uploaded to it.

Comment: This wont carry the file properly.